# Replace header in Word by VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

How should i change the scripte below, as it could replace date in header of a Word document? It works for the body of the Word document, but not for the header? What should i change?

```
Sub Main

 Dim iDate, sSearchValue, sReplaceValue

  iPath = C:/TEMP/test.docx
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objWSH = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  Set objWRD = GetObject("","Word.Application")

  iDate = Date
  objWRD.Visible = FALSE
  sSearchValue = "<DATE>" 
  sReplaceValue = iDate
  If sReplaceValue <> "" Then  
    strReplace objWRD, sSearchValue, sReplaceValue, 2
  End If  

  wrdTemplate.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath(iPath, "test.docx")
  wrdTemplate.Close
  objWRD.Quit
  iPath = objFSO.BuildPath(iPath, "test.doc")

End Sub

Main


Function strReplace(obj, sSearchValue, sReplaceValue, nType )

 obj.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
 obj.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

 obj.Selection.Find.Text = sSearchValue                ' Search string
 obj.Selection.Find.MatchCase = False
 obj.Selection.Find.MatchWholeWord = False
 obj.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = False
 obj.Selection.Find.MatchSoundsLike = False            ' True ????
 obj.Selection.Find.MatchAllWordForms = False
 obj.Selection.Find.Forward = True
 obj.Selection.Find.Wrap = 1                           ' = wdFindContinue
 obj.Selection.Find.Format = False
 obj.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = sReplaceValue   ' Replace string    

 obj.Selection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,nType      ' Type=2 wdReplaceAll 

End Function                 ' >>>>> strReplace <<<<<
```

This is all.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186629/searching-for-text-in-header-section-of-a-word-document

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But i need VBS instead VBA.

Comment: You're using the Word objects - calling Word functions are exactly the same when you're using a Word object in VBscript. Only difference between that and this is that you don't need to declare the variables as a specific type. Give it a try before you discount it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I found out, that my problem is not the VBA code, but the fact, that there is a column in the header, end this script doesnt find the text in columns.