# Finding text in word both in headings and pages

Tags: vba, find, ms-word

I am trying to find out if any cutomvariables are used in a document, however I have problems finding out if this is the case if it is defined in header or footer.

Here is my sub that loops through all customVariables:

```
Sub deleteCustomVarNotInUse()
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
 For i = 1 To Documents(doc).CustomDocumentProperties.Count

        If CustomProperties.findProperty(doc, Documents(doc).CustomDocumentProperties(i).name) Then

             'Delete variable...
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the function that I tried to modify from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186629/searching-for-text-in-header-section-of-a-word-document)

```
Public Function findProperty(doc As Document, findText As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    findProperty = False
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim intSecCount As Integer
    Dim intHFType As Integer

    Set rng = Documents(doc).Content
    rng.Find.Execute findText:="DOCPROPERTY*" & findText, Forward:=True
    If rng.Find.found = True Then
        findProperty = True
        Exit Function
    End If


    intSecCount = Documents(doc).Sections.Count
    For intSection = 1 To intSecCount
        With Documents(doc).Sections(intSection)
            For intHFType = 1 To 3
                Set rng = Documents(doc).Sections(intSection).Headers(intHFType).Range
                rng.Find.Execute findText:="DOCPROPERTY*" & findText, Forward:=True
                If rng.Find.found = True Then
                    findProperty = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next intHFType
        End With
    Next intSection



End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
   Public Function findProperty(doc As Document, findText As String) As Boolean
    Dim rngStory As word.Range
    Dim oFld As word.Field


    findProperty = False
    For Each rngStory In doc.StoryRanges
      Do
        For Each oFld In rngStory.Fields
          If oFld.Type = wdFieldDocProperty Then
              'Dig a little deeper and see what the field code contains.
              If InStr(UCase(oFld.Code.Text), UCase(findText)) Then
                findProperty = True
                Exit Function
              End If
          End If
        Next oFld
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next rngStory

End Function
```