# change name of CustomDocumentProperties in word with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I rename my customVariable in word? I have a Customvaraiable called "Document Number", but I would now like to rename it to _DocumentNumber"

I know I can create a new CustomVariable, delete the old one, but I am then struggling with how to update all the links in the document to the new one.

Edited code:

```
Sub test()
Dim A As word.Field
Dim FldUpd As String
Dim findText As String
Dim replaceText As String

findText = "Document Number"
replaceText = "_DocumentNumber"
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False

If ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(findText).value = "" Then Exit Sub

For Each A In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If A.result.Text = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(findText).value Then

            Call WordProperties.createCustomDocumentProperty(ActiveDocument.name, replaceText, ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(findText).value)
            ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True

            A.Select

            'DOCPROPERTY "Document number"  \* MERGEFORMAT
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = "DOCPROPERTY*" & findText
                .Replacement.Text = "DOCPROPERTY  " & replaceText
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
            End With
            tempBool = Selection.Find.Execute(replace:=wdReplaceAll)

            ' Refresh fields
            ActiveDocument.Fields.update

            ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
            If tempBool Then ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(findText).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Edited:
The problem is that the find method does not return true.

Comment: You still have create/delete of the docproperty inside the loop. But it isn't a property of the field, but of the document. So it belongs outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two things that must be separate.

First create the new doc property, using `ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add`

You do this only once, since the doc property exists only once.

Then you replace all existing references to the old doc property to the new one. Something like (excerpts from macro recorder)

```
' Show field source references (Alt+F9) so you can use Find&Replace
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "DOCPROPERTY  Document Number"
    .Replacement.Text = "DOCPROPERTY  _DocumentNumber"
    .Format = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Refresh fields
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
```

Then you can delete the old doc property.

**Edit:** to find and replace in all sections (including header & footer), see
[Searching for Text in Header Section of A Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186629/searching-for-text-in-header-section-of-a-word-document)

Comment: ok, so I combine your code with mine, to make sure that the find method finds occurrences in header and footer as well?

Comment: I think you will find that `ActiveDocument.Fields` doesn't include fields in header/footer as well. See edit. But you can use the same mechanism as in the linked post for the Fields collections of the sections. Then change `myField.Code`.

Comment: I also noted that the docproperty uses sometimes [space] and other times [space][space] and also different case. I guess this is due to that people have been editing the word document and it still works. So this might fail "DOCPROPERTY  Document Number"  because in some documents it might be  "DOCPROPERTY     Document number". Using wildcards in find method?

Comment: ActiveDocument.Fields does not find in headers and footers, thanks for heads up

Comment: Today I found a bug in my code: In the event "DOCPROPERTY test }{"DOCPROPERTY "Document Number"}  then this wildcard fails `pFindTxt = "DOCPROPERTY*" & findText` ANy idea how to fix it?

Comment: I guess this should work: pFindTxt = "DOCPROPERTY*[!x-z]" & findText to make it less greedy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, feel free to improve it:

```
Sub test()

    Dim findText As String
    Dim replaceText As String
    Dim temp As Variant

    findText = "Document Number"
    replaceText = "_DocumentNumber"

    On Error GoTo doesNotExist

    temp = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(findText).value

    pFindTxt = "DOCPROPERTY*" & findText
    pReplaceTxt = "DOCPROPERTY """ & replaceText

    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True

    'create the new variable
    Call WordProperties.createCustomDocumentProperty(ActiveDocument.name, replaceText, ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(findText).value)
    'Iterate through all story types in the current document
    For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

        'Iterate through all linked stories
        Do
            SearchAndReplaceInStory rngStory, pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
            On Error Resume Next
            Select Case rngStory.StoryType
                Case WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesHeaderStory, _
                     WdStoryType.wdPrimaryHeaderStory, _
                     WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesFooterStory, _
                     WdStoryType.wdPrimaryFooterStory, _
                     WdStoryType.wdFirstPageHeaderStory, _
                     WdStoryType.wdFirstPageFooterStory
                    If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
                            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                                SearchAndReplaceInStory oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Case Else
                    'Do Nothing
                End Select
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Get next linked story (if any)
                Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
            Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
        Next


        ' Refresh fields
        ActiveDocument.Fields.update

        ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
        Exit Sub

doesNotExist:
    MsgBox "CustomVariable " & findText & " does not exist"
    Exit Sub


End Sub

Public Sub SearchAndReplaceInStory(ByVal rngStory As word.Range, ByVal strSearch As String, ByVal strReplace As String)
    With rngStory.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = strSearch
        .Replacement.Text = strReplace
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```